# Make inputs accessible regardless of where they are

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a plugin that makes inputs checked work regardless of where they are located. I will be making lots of radio and checkbox inputs that will be buried in divs, but the inputs will need to control multiple divs when checked. I don't really want to make all of them work individually through jquery. I'd rather let css take care of what should happen when checked.

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(85, 183, 255, 0.25);
}

.box2 {
  left: 120px;
}

.box3 {
  left: 240px;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.b {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

.c {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 140px;
  background: rgba(85, 183, 255, 0.25);
}

.con2 {
  left: 120px;
}

.con3 {
  left: 240px;
}

.alter {
  postion: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  left: 10px;
  top: 60px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.radio1:checked ~ .me1 {
  background: green;
}

.radio2:checked ~ .me2 {
  height: 100px;
  top: 50px;
}

.radio2:checked ~ .me3 {
  transform: scale(2px);
}
```

```html
<div class="a box1">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">
      <input type="radio" name="radio" class="radio1">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="a box2">
  <div class="b">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" class="radio2">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="a box3">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">
      <input type="radio" name="radio" class="radio3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container con1">
  <div class="alter me1"></div>
</div>
<div class="container con2">
  <div class="alter me3"></div>
</div>
<div class="container con3">
  <div class="alter me3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, what you intend to do, but maybe this helps.
The code triggers as soon as one radio button is checked and afterwards checks if all radio button boxes are selected.

You may probably do something else then, instead of showing a continue link.
Hope this helps, otherwise describe more clear, what you intend to do.

```
$(":radio").change(function() {
        var names = {};
        $(':radio').each(function() {
            names[$(this).attr('name')] = true;
        });
        var count = 0;
        $.each(names, function() {
            count++;
        });
        if ($(':radio:checked').length === count) {
            $('#linkContinue').show();
        }
    }).change();
```

Comment: The answer you provide did not do anything. Sorry if the question is not clear. I guess what I'm looking for is a jquery/javascript algorithm that allows the (html inputs) and (css:checked functions) to execute…

Comment: Css does not allow (html inputs) to talk to grandparents siblings - children

Comment: I need some code that allows the (html inputs) to (talk to/control) anyone from anywhere with (css:checked) within the html